# Error en selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Estoy realizando un codigo sencillo con python para abrir chrome y entrar a twitter, pero al momento de iniciar el programa se para y crashea.

El codigo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def login(driver):
    driver.get('https://twitter.com/home')
    time.sleep(4)

def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options ,executable_path=r'C:\Users\Maxi\Proyectos Python\Selenium Robots\chromedriver.exe')
    login(driver)

main()
```

Este es el errror:

> [12776:13276:0116/141657.956:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [14:16:57.956] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.
> [12776:13276:0116/141657.958:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [14:16:57.959] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
> [12776:13276:0116/141657.962:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [14:16:57.963] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
> [12776:13276:0116/141657.963:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [14:16:57.963] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Answer (score 0):

No sé a qué se debe el error. Pero te podría dar algunas ideas para probar:

- Prueba a quitar el parámetro options.
- Actualiza Selenium:

> python3 -m pip install —upgrade selenium

- Descarga nuevamente el driver de chrome, en su versión más reciente.
- Alternativamente puedes probar a usar geckodriver para Firefox.